# Bootstrap modal remove some space at the bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I tried with no success to remove some space at the bottom of a Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalDetails" role="dialog" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:red;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-3x pad-r-10"></i>Informations détaillées d un compte</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body pad-0">
            <iframe id="If_accountdetails" name="If_accountdetails" width="100%" height="400" style="overflow-x:hidden !important;border: 0px;" class="noborder" src="about:blank"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

We can see a red line corresponding to the modal-content despite a margin and a padding to 0px:
[Modal with space (red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEmvN.jpg)

Does anyone know how to remove this space?

Thanks.

Comment: any css attached here?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, if there is any css attached to the page ?

Comment: in your css use iframe { display: block; } , it should work

Comment: or if you don't use an external CSS file, add display: block in your style in the iframe line

Comment: Yes thanks, display: block; worked like a charm :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a guess (please provide some CSS), but I'd assume the issue is the `iframe`.  `iframe`s are "inline frames", so they are affected by line height, vertical alignment, and whitespace.  Try adding `display:block` to the `iframe` to override this behavior and the red gap should disappear.

Comment: Yes thanks, display: block; worked like a charm :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's working. Upvote from my side