# How to reduce the blank space at the bottom, in a Bootstrap Modal Dialog without footer tag

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46382643/13815916) post to make a bootstrap fullscreen modal, but I didnt' implemented the SCSS code as mentioned there.

My question is: [how to reduce the bottom blank space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cENnR.png) at the bottom of the modal, for example to 10px using CSS? intentionally, I dont' need the modal footer tag. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39418801/13815916) before asking but, I'm not using an iframe tag.

How to achieve this? Any help will be grateful. Thank you!!!

Here is the modal HTML code. The button how make a call is not there.

```
<div class="fade modal" id="pdf" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="pdfTitle"></h5>
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" data-pg-collapsed>
            <body>
            <object id="pdfDoc" data="something" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
                <embed class="embed" src="path/doc_file.pdf#toolbar=0" type="application/pdf" />
            </object>
            </body>
            </htm>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved when `<object>` has the height attribute equal to 100% as shown below.

```
<object id="pdfDoc" data="" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
```